# Triac Trigger Problem

Tags: triac

Could someone please tell me why the TRIAC is not triggering as it should? After zero crossing is detected, timer has programmed delay from 1ms to 9ms, set by potentiometer. The trigger signal is correct, i think, yet the TRIAC's output is not getting chopped as in phase angle control.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 50mA to trigger the triac (100mA in QIV), and you appear to be getting neither. You should avoid QIV, the triac is much less sensitive in that quadrant.

Your drive signal is inverted, it should be **low** to turn on Q4 to trigger the triac, so if there was sufficient gate current available the triac would remain on continuously.

It may work when you fix the gate drive, for half-waves only, because your continuous drive is being limited by R7 (100 ohms) and thus C1 is not helping. But there is *still* not enough current to reliably trigger the triac in QIV, so re-think your design there. Negative gate drive is better.

Remember, **always read the data sheet through to the end**. The datasheet mentions 50mA on the front but the fine print tells you it applies only to QI, QII and QIII (and only with the junction at room temperature, if you want it to work when cold you need more current).

Comment: i tried inverting signal from pic to obtain non-inverted signal. triac still unfire. so current is not enough. i have used the driver proposed by TI (slaa043a) for most triacs, because of current needed, would in this case be an option to use two parallel pins from pic as to reach 50mA ?

Comment: Simulate (or *carefully* measure) the gate current and figure out what is going wrong with your driver. I don't recommend trying to drive directly from a PIC- you can't get +100mA sourced that way, and you should have perhaps 120mA, **not** 50mA- that is not enough, for reasons I explained.

Comment: Another reason is that the triac gate is a voltage source when it is conducting and you don't really want to be injecting that into your PIC port pin.

Answer (score 0):

This Question, @Spehro’s answer and the comments catched my attention to search some more.
I found a very interesting [Application Note from ST Electronics](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an440-triac-control-with-a-microcontroller-powered-from-a-positive-supply-stmicroelectronics.pdf), covering exactly the triggering of Triac by MCU. It explains the triggering features and even show how to calculate some circuits presented, and their limitations.
Here are some examples, driven at different voltage levels and depending of the output type the MCU port:

[image]

There is a section that explains and illustrates exactly the triggering being correctly done in the First quadrant, **Q1** (blue), while showing the problem of not triggering properly a Triac in the **Q4** (red), but it could be triggered in the **Q3** (green):

[image]

The ST’s AN has a lot more information that is worth consulting.