# Triac dimmer burned transformer as load

Tags: triac

Why did the dimmer burned the linear transformer? It is a MOT transformer, secondary rewound with 7 turns and a resistive heating element of 800w. While the transformer worked fine at line 220AC, burned while connected to the dimmer(phase angle).
[image]

[image]

Comment: What’s the load on the other side of the transformer?

Comment: a resistive element, aprox. 800w, spiral coil

Comment: What part of the transformer burned?

Comment: the secondary, but cant say for sure. because the damage, can't confirm where ignited...

Comment: Ignited by prolonged heat or instantaneous flashover?

Comment: prolonged...after power-up at max power, 10sec later humming, 20sec later louder humming, 30sec fire and shutdown. Triac very hot, but no damage, transformer burned.

Comment: forgot to mention, dimmer works fine with 400w lamp. trigger signal occures once after zero cross, not burst, as i saw recommended for capacitive supplies, which cannot deliver high power.

Comment: What gauge did you rewind the secondary with?

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember when [I told you about **Quadrant IV** on the triac](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372751/triac-trigger-problem)?

Remember when I said that if you don't put enough current into the gate (>100mA) the triac will trigger only on the (positive) half-cycles?

That is equivalent to putting half-wave rectified DC through your transformer primary and "burning" is exactly what we would expect to happen.

You need to either stop trying to trigger in Q-IV or to put enough current through the gate to trigger in any of the quadrants.

And put a fuse in series with the transformer primary. It may not save the triac but it should save the transformer winding.

Comment: i have modified the circuit, changed resistor values to allow enough current. with resistive load worked fine. i used a 10A fuse which blowed, so decided to test further without fuse, leading to burned transformer.

Comment: So the schematic above is not what you tested?

Comment: in that case, my only option is to use bridge rectifier instead of capacitive supply or can i use signal burst ?

Comment: the schematic is the exact circuit from the other post, following your advice about current just modified 2 resistor from driver to get more current. the board is assembled from that schematic. R4 and R5 were modified.

Comment: It still sounds like you were getting half wave across the transformer. The inductive load makes it harder to reach holding current if you are very close to the zero crossing. If your power supply can handle it you can try running 120mA continuous to the gate (get rid of R2 and make sure R5 is low enough value- about 30R and is rated for enough power (about 1W), and probably have to reduce R4 to maybe 300 ohms)

Comment: the power supply can't handle that, as capacitive ones depend on capacitor value, i am using 1uF in order to obtain ~12mA. is a bridge rectifier advisable or same capacitive supply with pulse train ? another fail i've made beside undertriggering is "Keep the triac in conduction: (avoid gate control by a single short pulse)" .....

Comment: Yes, that's a problem with an inductive load. You have to keep the gate current above the trigger current long enough for the current to rise to the holding current. If your gate current is tailing off over time you'll get half-waves in Q-IV. Can't you generate a NEGATIVE 5V voltage wrt the triac MT1 and use that? It's easy with a cap dropper supply. Then you use an NPN transistor and pull the gate towards ground (MT1 is tied to +5V). Let me know if this isn't clear enough. You could also use an optotriac MOCxxxx to trigger the main triac.

Comment: please have a look at updated main post. let me know if this is what you mean. the reason for using pic instead MOC, just to understand more about zero crossing, and also very easy potentiometer interfacing and other controls.

Comment: I am suggesting using the PIC to trigger something like an MOC3023, and use that to trigger the main triac.